# Why is my variable not displaying the correct amount

Tags: android

I am using android studio to do a shopping app.

I first created a Word class with two parameters (product and price) then created an arrayList called productList and added my products:

```
productList.add(new Word("First ", 10));
productList.add(new Word("Second ", 20));
productList.add(new Word("Third ", 30));
productList.add(new Word("Fourth ", 40));
```

I then did ViewPager to display them.

The layout of each page in the View pager consists of two TextViews (product and price) and then a quantity value and a button for adding the product to cart and a button for checking out.
The layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/checkoutButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Checkout"
        android:onClick="startCheckout"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        tools:text="item" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvTitle"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/secondText"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:onClick="decrement"
            android:text="-" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:onClick="increment"
            android:text="+" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addProductButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/btnToggle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="add product to cart"

        />
    


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnToggle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Toggle Orientation" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

What I want to do is to add the price every time the user clicks on "addProductButton"
so I created a Button object of the button with the id "addProductButton" and then added a clickListener to it.

```
addProductButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                thisPrice = Integer.parseInt(priceTextView.getText().toString());
                totalPrice += thisPrice * quantity;
                totalPriceTextView.setText(String.valueOf(totalPrice));
            }
        });
```

thisPrice refers to the int value of the price TextView of the product

the totalPrice is an int that I initialized and gave it a value of 0 and it refers to the overall total price

the totalPriceTextView is a TextView in another layout and I inflated its layout before initializing it and it refers to the TextView that will have the final overall price (totalPrice variable)

the quantity variable is referring to an integer that I initialized already and it will increase and decrease according to increment and decrement methods everytime the user clicks on "+" and "-" buttons

My problem is that when running my application, I am not facing any errors but the total price TextView is always showing 0 and is not updating to the new value.

Comment: whats the value of quantity initialy?

Comment: have you tried to debug this with breakpoints ? stepping through the project ?

Comment: The initial value of quantity is 2 but as the user clicks on the “+” and “-“ buttons, it changes

Comment: I tried adding breakpoints on the last two lines of the click listener but the code debugger code isn’t showing me any values. I also tried using the log but it is also not showing.